# Call Directory Extension CallKit does't recognize numbers with more than 9 digits

Tags: ios, callkit

I'm working with CallKit and developing an app with a Call Directory Extension. I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/701-callkit-tutorial-for-ios) and I'm currently test the capability of identify numbers that the user does't have in his contacts and show an ID from my app, but although is working perfectly with numbers of 1 to 9 digits, for example 123456, when I set numbers with 10 or more digits, iOs doesn't recognize the number. After a day and a half of google it, I've have found no information about that. If anyone can help me I'll appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

The method for set the phone numbers for recognize:

```
private func addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
        // Retrieve phone numbers to identify and their identification labels from data store. For optimal performance and memory usage when there are many phone numbers,
        // consider only loading a subset of numbers at a given time and using autorelease pool(s) to release objects allocated during each batch of numbers which are loaded.
        //
        // Numbers must be provided in numerically ascending order.

        let allPhoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 123456789, 1_888_555_5555 ]
        let labels = [ "ID test", "Local business" ]

        for (phoneNumber, label) in zip(allPhoneNumbers, labels) {
            context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber, label: label)
        }
    }
```

With this code, when I simulate a call with the number 123456789, iOS shows the tag "ID test" and that's correct, but if I add any digit, for example 0 at the end: 1234567890, iOS does't show anything when I simulate a call. I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I presume the numbers in your question are just examples, but you must ensure that you add numbers in ascending order; so 612123456789 must be added *after* 612123456780

Comment: Hi Paulw11. That's right, those numbers are the ones I've used to simulate calls, and I've made sure to place them in ascending order. So, 1234567890 is still going before 18885555555, I think.

Comment: Then I am not sure. My app loads up standard 12 digit e.164 numbers as per my earlier comment and they work.

Comment: Well, so far, I have seen that with 10 and 11 digit numbers it doesn't work, but it does with 9 and 12 digit numbers. I have no idea why

Comment: Perhaps the numbers aren't matching. Maybe whatever you are using to spoof the callerid doesn't send 10 or 11 digit numbers correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a bunch of tests I could made it work. The point was that **the phone must contain the full country code and the area code**. So for example 00_52_55_4567_8932 877 or +52_55_4567_8932 both will work. But 55_4567_8932 and 4567_8932 will not work. I hope this can help someone else in the future. Thank you all!